# Are C# Collections value types or reference Types?

Tags: c#, collections

I am busy learning C# here, Are C# Collections value types or reference Types?, Since Arrays a reference types and I know Strings are reference types as well.

Thank You.

Comment: Value types are structs. You can check each collection type's definition (eg in the documentation) but I don't know of any BCL collection type that is actually defined as a struct. You can create your own of course

Comment: *Why* are you asking? Why would you care whether they are value types or not? Are you trying to avoid the need for memberwise copying? Are you trying to emulate C++ semantics?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos this is a good question and what do you mean by 'care?'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could create a value type collection (so a `struct MyCollection<T> : IEnumerable<T>`), but it would be nearly useless (because you could make it read-only, and it would be simple, or you could try to make it mutable, but it would be very difficult to make it "value-type" copiable, so that a copy of the collection is a distinct entity from the original) (and note that it would be still nearly useless, because if you use a value type through one if its interfaces, you normally box it). So in the end, **don't** :-)

All the .NET "stock" collections that I can remember are reference types. So arrays, `List<>`, `ArrayList`, `Dictionary<,>`, ...

Comment: Since .NET 4.5 (Visual Studio 2012), the value type (`struct`) `System.ArraySegment<>` is a collection type! For example, you can `foreach` through `new ArraySegment<string>(new[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", }, 2, 3)`. This struct simply holds a reference to the array (arrays are mutable reference type). Copy-by-value is no problem since it is a shallow copy. It is only the reference which is copied because of the value semantics. So it makes sense to have a `struct`-type collection type when it is some kind of wrapper around something else.